# JSF - outputFormat tries to parse argument to number

Tags: javascript, jsf, localization

Trying to use primefaces calendar with localization. I thought about adding the javascript properties array into the corresponding locale message properties file.

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales

```
primefacesLocale=PrimeFaces.locales['de'] = \u007B closeText: 'Schlie\u00DFen', prevText: 'Zur\u00FCck', nextText: 'Weiter', {0} weekHeader: 'Woche', firstDay: 1, isRTL: false, showMonthAfterYear: false, yearSuffix: '', timeOnlyTitle: 'Nur Zeit', timeText: 'Zeit', hourText: 'Stunde', minuteText: 'Minute', secondText: 'Sekunde', currentText: 'Aktuelles Datum', ampm: false, month: 'Monat', week: 'Woche', day: 'Tag', allDayText: 'Ganzer Tag'\u007D;
```

Using it like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <h:outputFormat value="#{msg.primefacesLocale}" escape="false">
        <f:param value="test"/>
    </h:outputFormat>
</script>
```

*Month- and weekday names should be retrieved via el functions, `test` value is just for testing*

Results in:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number:  closeText: 'Schließen'
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(MessageFormat.java:1420)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:479)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(MessageFormat.java:381)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutputMessageRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputMessageRenderer.java:113)
```

Whats wrong here?

**Edit:**

Using: `<h:outputText value="#{msg.primefacesLocale}" escape="false">` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`MessageFormat` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) has some special characters. The `{`, `}` and `'`. The `{` and `}` represents the start and end of format argument index. The `'` is an escape character (like as `\` is in strings).

The `\u007B` which you've there in the beginning represents the `{`. It should actually have been escaped by surrounding it with `'`. The same for the ending `\u007D` which represents the `}`.

```
primefacesLocale=PrimeFaces.locales['de'] = '\u007B' closeText: 'Schlie\u00DFen', prevText: 'Zur\u00FCck', nextText: 'Weiter', {0} weekHeader: 'Woche', firstDay: 1, isRTL: false, showMonthAfterYear: false, yearSuffix: '', timeOnlyTitle: 'Nur Zeit', timeText: 'Zeit', hourText: 'Stunde', minuteText: 'Minute', secondText: 'Sekunde', currentText: 'Aktuelles Datum', ampm: false, month: 'Monat', week: 'Woche', day: 'Tag', allDayText: 'Ganzer Tag''\u007D';
```

You can by the way also just put those `{` and `}` plain vanilla in the string.

```
primefacesLocale=PrimeFaces.locales['de'] = '{' closeText: 'Schlie\u00DFen', prevText: 'Zur\u00FCck', nextText: 'Weiter', {0} weekHeader: 'Woche', firstDay: 1, isRTL: false, showMonthAfterYear: false, yearSuffix: '', timeOnlyTitle: 'Nur Zeit', timeText: 'Zeit', hourText: 'Stunde', minuteText: 'Minute', secondText: 'Sekunde', currentText: 'Aktuelles Datum', ampm: false, month: 'Monat', week: 'Woche', day: 'Tag', allDayText: 'Ganzer Tag''}';
```

Note: as said, the `'` is an escape character, if you want to represent it as-is, use two of them.

```
primefacesLocale=PrimeFaces.locales['de'] = '{' closeText: ''Schlie\u00DFen'', prevText: ''Zur\u00FCck'', nextText: ''Weiter'', {0} weekHeader: ''Woche'', firstDay: 1, isRTL: false, showMonthAfterYear: false, yearSuffix: '''', timeOnlyTitle: ''Nur Zeit'', timeText: ''Zeit'', hourText: ''Stunde'', minuteText: ''Minute'', secondText: ''Sekunde'', currentText: ''Aktuelles Datum'', ampm: false, month: ''Monat'', week: ''Woche'', day: ''Tag'', allDayText: ''Ganzer Tag'''}';
```

This is in turn however invalid JSON. The string keys and values should be doublequoted (although most webbrowsers are forviging in this).

Comment: The param value I build in java needs escaping the same way? Not sure If I wanna use it anyway. Just builded the function to provide to primefaces team.